# How do I change my pendrive's icon and restore hidden files after it has become infected?

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, virus

My pendrive had a virus on it. I scanned it with Kaspersky and Malwarebytes, and it caught many viruses.

1. My pendrive icon has been changed to a folder icon. I tried to change it, but it's not working.   I know that formatting will solve this, but without formatting, how could I do that?
2. I had a folder on my pendrive, but the virus has changed it to become a hidden file. I can only view it when I uncheck "Show system files" from *Tools » Folder Options*. I am unable to change it back to a normal folder using "change icon".

Answer (score 0):

Format it. No question.

Copy all the files and folders you have to your HD, and copy the files within the hidden folder to a new folder on the HD with the same name. As long as you have scanned these files, they shouldn't do anything there. Then format.

Comment: I don't think so that the format is the only option. I've faced this problem many times just scan with an antivirus which should be able to catch those viruses and delete them and then remove your USB from the system and re-plug it and yeah you are back with default icon.

Comment: kk avirk i will try what you have told